NestJS/Queues: How can one get/check if a Queue has been updated?
I want to keep track of form names in my application as they get updated.
I am assuming a Queue in NestJS could be something like an array [], where you can push in the ids/form Numbers i.e. [123, 456, 789] in memory and while your application is running it has this additional process kind of like a service/web worker which can run in the background and could be used to store like an in-memory data structure.
I have been able to figure out how one would create a ProducerService in NestJS:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Form, Job, JobOpts } from '@shared/config/app.config'; // Import the missing 'JobOpts' type
import { InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Queue } from 'bull';

@Injectable()
export class DSQueueProducerService { 
  constructor(
    @InjectQueue('form-notification-queue') private readonly formNotificationQueue: Queue,
  ) {}
  async addToFormQueue(data: Form, opts?: JobOpts): Promise<Job> {  

    const job = await this.formNotificationQueue.add(data, opts);

    return job;
  }
}

And you'd have a notifySubscribers function that would push a form number in the queue. But what I want is a way to check out the Queue if a form number exists or not?
I've looked at a lot examples but all them have a method in the consumer class with a param?
import { Process, Processor } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Form } from '@shared/config/app.config';
import { Job } from 'bull';
@Processor('form-notification-queue')
export class DSQueueConsumerService {
  @Process('form-job')
  async getFormsFromQueue(job: Job<Form>): Promise<void> { <--- param
    console.log('Processing form job with data', job.data);
    console.log(job.data);
    console.log('completed!!');
  }
}

I'd like to check the queue first? And if the form doesn't exist add it to the queue...
  async notifySubscribers(tableItemAudit: DSTableItem<FormUrlMap>, formReq: DSFormRequestModel): Promise<void> {
    
    const forms: Form = await this.dSQueueConsumerService.getFormsFromQueue();
 
    if (!forms.includes(formReq.formId)) {
      await this.dsDSQueueProducerService.addToFormQueue(formReq.formNumber)
    } else {
      this.logService.info(`Form ${formReq.formNumber} is already in the queue`);
    }
  }

That is sort of psuedo-code, but could anyone please offer how one would read the values in a NestJS Queue?
